# PHP/HTML Strike out words in one line if statement

Tags: php, html

I'm working on a PHP script that will strike out all words that are less than 3 characters long.  I'm using a one line if statement in my php and I'm getting the error unexpected ;
But there is no ; in my code.  If someone could give me a kick in the right direction for this it would be awesome.

```
?><td><?php echo (checkWord($input))?$input:?><del><?php $input?></del></td><?php
```

The function checkWord takes a string as an input and returns false if the string is less than 3 characters in length.  Otherwise it will return true.

I'm sure it's something simple that I neglected to put in the line, all help is appreciated and thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <td><?php echo (checkWord($input)) ? $input : "<del>$input</del>"; ?></td>
```